# How to add one more column into GROUP BY expression? Oracle - SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, sum

[DATABASE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nufE6.jpg)

SQL Command:

```
SELECT CUST_ID,SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD),CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT
CUST_ID,AMOUNT_SOLD,CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT,
TO_CHAR(TIME_ID,'YYYY')AS YEAR FROM SH.SALES 
JOIN SH.CUSTOMERS USING (CUST_ID))
WHERE YEAR = '2001' 
GROUP BY CUST_ID;
```

> "not a GROUP BY expression"

Without CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT(after SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) it works, but that column is mandatory for me and I need to keep it tracked.

The results should be for every Customer(CUST_ID) there should be all summerized sales(SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) in year 2001 AND his credit limit(CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT)... It works without credit limit, but I need to work it with it.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says..  You added CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT to your select list, but not your GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT CUST_ID,SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD),CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT
CUST_ID,AMOUNT_SOLD,CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT,
TO_CHAR(TIME_ID,'YYYY')AS YEAR FROM SH.SALES 
JOIN SH.CUSTOMERS USING (CUST_ID))
WHERE YEAR = '2001' 
GROUP BY CUST_ID,CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT;
```

I would say there are other issues with this too (why the DISTINCT?, etc) but that should get you by the GROUP BY error.

Comment: Well, good queston, I've added DISTINCT when I was reaching out for the solution, but I guess It's not needed, going to try this one

Comment: if cust_id is a primary key , distinct is useless, if not , sum is wrong

Comment: It works, I would swear I was trying this one too, but It seems I didn't, thanks alot :)

Comment: your sum is incorrect, if a cust_id has several same amount_sold.

Comment: It works withotu DISTINCT as it should... Or at least results seems to be OK when i checked them with my collegue

Answer (score 0):

you must have ,CUST_CREDIT in your group by,
you can re select all with

```
select  cust_id, sumid from (select SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) sumid, your code
group by "all fields execpt calculate fields (grouped) sum, max etc  )
```